# PHP5.3 + IIS 7 + FastCGI - Parse error when using an array from a function

Tags: php, iis, iis-7, fastcgi

First time in a **long** time since I've used PHP with IIS, however I've hit a bit of a deadlock when it comes to this line

`if($this->debug) var_dump($this->_handle->error . " L" . debug_backtrace()[0]["line"]);`

On my Debian development box - this will work perfectly (albeit not the best coding style in the world)

However on the Server 2008 R2 box with PHP5.3 + IIS 7 + FastCGI running, it will throw a parse error 
`Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' in C:\inetpub\linkfinder\dev\dbhandler.php on line 94`

My PHP.ini similar between the two boxes through running a `diff` against them.

I will be also modifying the code today across the project to move away from this coding style but I was interested in if it is this a common limitation of PHP in IIS or am I missing a config setting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to do *function array dereferencing* which is the [latest feature(s) of PHP 5.4](https://php.net/manual/en/migration54.new-features.php) and not available on PHP 5.3.

You need to rewrite like this for that to work..

```
<?php
if($this->debug) {
   $backtrace = debug_backtrace();
   var_dump($this->_handle->error . " L" . $backtrace[0]["line"]);
}
?>
```

Comment: So I am indeed! Thanks for the swift answer!